What's the recommended way of function calling in Microsoft Autogen?
I saw that function calling in Autogen is done in several ways. Official tutorials use the register function or user_proxy.register_for_execution methods, while some of the 3rd party tutorials I saw use "functions": (function name) with llm_config or using function_map within the agent constructor for tool calls. The latter way, with function_map, multiple functions can be assigned at once, although these two approaches didn't work for me, but only the methods in the documentation.
Can someone please explain to me the correct and effective way to deal with functions or tool calls? And also in the official tutorial, it mentioned that we don't have to construct a function definition like OpenAI's function calling, but some others seemed to be still practicing it with Autogen. So, is it really necessary?
using "functions" :
SQL_executor = AssistantAgent(
name="ExecutorAgent",    
system_message="excecute SQL Queries."} .query = query ", 
llm_config={"config_list": config_list , "functions":execute_sql_query }, 
code_execution_config={"work_dir":"coding", "use_docker":False},   

)
using function_map
SQL_executor = AssistantAgent(
name="ExecutorAgent",    
system_message="excecute SQL Queries."} .query = query ", 
llm_config={"config_list": config_list}, 
code_execution_config={"work_dir":"coding", "use_docker":False},   
function_map = function_name   )

official documents :
user_proxy.register_for_execution(name="calculator")(calculator)

or
register_function(
calculator,
caller=assistant,  
executor=user_proxy, 
name="calculator", 
description="A simple calculator", 
)

